# NewtonSoft.JSON Deserialize - Not deserializing correctly. (VB.NET)

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON return however it either errors when I try to deserialize at the highest level, or doesn't error and just returns null values if I start deeper into the json.

I just get "null" returns for the rest of my deserialization - I have successfully deserialized `messages` separately but when I try to do the whole lot it just returns nulls to all my values.

It provides are error when I attempt to deserialize at `response`, I'm not clear what exactly is wrong.

Model

````
Public Class response
    
    public property http_code as string
    public property response_code as string
    public property response_msg as string
    public property data as smsdata
    
End Class

Public Class smsdata
    
    public property total_price as string 
    public property total_count as string
    public property queued_count as string
    public property messages as messages
    
End Class
Public Class messages
    
    Public property messages as list(of message)
    
End Class

Public Class message
    
    Public Property direction as string
    <JsonProperty("date")>
    Public property daterange as string
    <JsonProperty("to")>
    public property recipient as string
    public property body as string
    public property from as string
    public property schedule as string
    public property message_id as string
    public property message_parts as string
    public property message_price as string
    public property from_email as string
    public property list_id as string
    public property custom_string as string
    public property contact_id as string
    public property user_id as string
    public property subaccount_id as string
    public property country as string
    public property carrier as string
    public property status as string 
End Class```

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        
        dim jsonstring as string = "{ 'http_code': 200, 'response_code': 'SUCCESS', 'response_msg': 'Messages queued for delivery.', 'data': { 'total_price': 0.0516, 'total_count': 2, 'queued_count': 2, 'messages': [ { 'direction': 'out', 'date': 1637744634, 'to': '+44771111111111', 'body': 'test message, please ignore 1', 'from': 'Shield', 'schedule': 1637744634, 'message_id': 'A3F48CA8-79E6-416F-A8C6-7660BD7B7632', 'message_parts': 1, 'message_price': '0.0258', 'from_email': null, 'list_id': null, 'custom_string': '', 'contact_id': null, 'user_id': 100525, 'subaccount_id': 116285, 'country': 'GB', 'carrier': 'O2', 'status': 'SUCCESS' }, { 'direction': 'out', 'date': 1637744634, 'to': '+4477222222222', 'body': 'test message, please ignore 2', 'from': 'Clubcare', 'schedule': 1637744634, 'message_id': '670E96E2-ED4F-4FAB-8594-D49B244EA2C3', 'message_parts': 1, 'message_price': '0.0258', 'from_email': null, 'list_id': null, 'custom_string': '', 'contact_id': null, 'user_id': 100525, 'subaccount_id': 116285, 'country': 'GB', 'carrier': 'O2', 'status': 'SUCCESS' } ], '_currency': { 'currency_name_short': 'GBP', 'currency_prefix_d': '£', 'currency_prefix_c': 'p', 'currency_name_long': 'British Pounds' } } }"
        
        dim results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of response)(jsonstring)
        
    End Sub
End Module
````

Comment: @dba the single parentheses works - I have a working earlier example where I deserialize JUST the "messages" element. This is failing as I scale up.

Example single parantheses.
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your code and the sample data:

```
Public Class smsdata
    
    public property total_price as string 
    public property total_count as string
    public property queued_count as string
    public property messages as List (Of message)
    
End Class
```

should do the trick and you can dump the Messages Class

(as of single qoutes: I never used them, but VS-Code mark them as error, however :-))

Comment: This worked - also single quotes worked fine.